# How to have a default title for a web page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

It seems straightforward enough, and testing it, it actually works:

```
<title>Default text</title>
```

In the Masterpage. And:

```
<%@ Page Title="Specific name"...
```

in the specific page. Or in its codebehind:

```
Title = "Specific name";
```

So why am I asking? Because searching for it I've found all sorts of more complicated methods for doing that. (Yes. In Asp.net.)

So is there any drawback to the way I wrote above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not sure what you've found but that's how it is normally done.**
*Master page has the default, with overrides from specific pages.*

An alternative (and I'm not specifying it's better) is to use a Content Placeholder.

**On Master Page**

```
<title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PageTitle" runat="server">Default Title</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</title>
```

**On specific page**

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PageTitle" runat="server">Specific Title</asp:Content>
```

But the drawback is that it's not as easy to set the title from code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to know here that the `<title></title>` can not change from the code behind, or from the page declaration if is NOT inside the **header** with `runat="server"` So only if you have like that :

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Default Title</title>
</head>
```

you can have it as default, and then change it on pages. If the head is not runat="server" then the code behind can not find it to change it and the default title is shown.

All the rest stands as they are, I also use the same way, a default title on the master page, that I change it from the page if I can, or if not the default title is shown.